# Do root's supplementary groups behave differently than regular account ones for NFS shares?

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs, group, access-control

OS: Linux CentOS 7, NFSv4

On one machine I exported an NFS share group-owned by the *nfsgroup* with 2770 privileges for group collaboration:

```
groupadd -g 5000 nfsgroup
chown nobody:nfsgroup /home/groupshare
chmod 2770 /home/groupshare
```

Then, on the other machine I add the same group and assign it to the root user. I then try to access the mounted NFS share and get a 'Permission denied' error:

```
groupadd -g 5000 nfsgroup
usermod -a -G nfsgroup root
ls -l /mnt/groupshare       # Permission denied!
```

Note: For this I tried to re-login as root and even reboot the machine, the result is the same: Permission denied.

I then do the same thing for the regular account (named *user*) and have no access problems

```
usermod -a -G nfsgroup user
su - user
ls -l /mnt/groupshare      # Works as expected, no permission errors
```

The only way I can access the share under the root is by changing the effective group (despite supplementary *nfsgroup* is there):

```
su - root
newgrp nfsgroup
ls -l /mnt/groupshare     # No permission errors
```

I find this behavior inconsistent and weird. Can someone please shed a light on why it behaves this way?

One piece of information, that maybe somehow relevant is as follows. Both the `id` (under *user* account) and `id user` return the same output, in particular ***groups=1000(user),5000(nfsgroup)***, while the `id` (under *root* account) produces ***groups=0(root)*** and `id root` outputs, as expected, ***groups=0(root),5000(nfsgroup)***.

Comment: I might have had a possible solution if you hadn't done a `chown nobody`, but with that\ command... NFS has a security option whereby `root` on a client is treated as `nobody`.

Comment: Yep, you're almost right. Please see my own elaborate answer for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found what caused the problem. When NFS client accesses an NFS share, the server checks UID and GID of the accessing user. And by default NFS server comes with `root_squash` option enabled, that assigns NFS client accessing the share as root the UID/GID of *nfsnobody*.

After I had added the `no_root_squash` option to the export in `/etc/exports` file the problem disappeared.

Apparently when NFS server 'squashes' root's UID/GID it disregards the supplementary groups altogether (seems wrong to me, but probably the NFSv4 standard thinks differently).