# Linux user groups and file system permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs, group

Assume I have groups `G1`, and `G2`, and user `U`.

User `U` is a member of both groups, but `G1` is it's primary group.

In my file system there is a folder `F` which is accessible by `G2`. Now if `U` wants to access `F` the only way for it is to do `newgrp G2`, and then access, which is not what I want my users do all the time.

What should I do?

Concrete example:

```
ajalali@ws47lx:/projects/gchrupala$ stat .
  File: `.'
  Size: 17          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1048576 directory
Device: 15h/21d Inode: 150         Links: 3
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 6052/gchrupala)   Gid: ( 6000/nis_users)
Access: 2015-03-05 15:34:46.260662858 +0100
Modify: 2013-03-05 16:35:16.000000000 +0100
Change: 2013-06-10 20:40:25.418034444 +0200
 Birth: -
ajalali@ws47lx:/projects/gchrupala$ id
uid=1004(ajalali) gid=1001(ajalali) groups=1001(ajalali),6000(nis_users),6060(admin),6061(sudo),1625200000(admins),1625200001(lsv_local),1625200035(compute_server_users),1625200036(contact_server_users)
ajalali@ws47lx:/projects/gchrupala$ mkdir tmp
mkdir: cannot create directory `tmp': Permission denied
```

The user (ajalali) is a member of the group that owns the current folder (6000), but can not make anything there, cause it's primary group (1001) is not the group that owns current folder.

It will only work if the user does `newgrp nis_users` first, and then try to make a folder there.

Comment: That's not normal. Having `G2` as a supplementary group should be enough to get its permissions. You should not need to `newgrp` to it. Is `/projects` or `/projects/gchrupala` perchance an unusual type of filesystem?

Comment: This is on the server:

`/dev/sdb1 on /projects type xfs (rw)`

And this is on the client:

`fs1lx.lsv.uni-saarland.de:/projects on /projects type nfs (rw,nodev,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=134.96.116.8,mountvers=3,mountport=39732,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=134.96.116.8,_netdev)`

Comment: I *think* it should work on NFS too, but I have no recent experience with that. In any case, since it's NFS, do check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171284/do-roots-supplementary-groups-behave-differently-than-regular-account-ones-for

Comment: install package `acl` on linux box and use `setfacl` command.

Comment: @Celada: that post is specific to the UID of `root`, I'm aware of that problem. In my case, non of the users are root.

Comment: The same question was asked by the same user on SU: https://superuser.com/questions/886289/linux-user-groups-and-file-system-permissions

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: yes it was. It was also asked on stackoverflow, and then a user suggested I post on these two places. There are just too many stackexchange places, and neither people who ask nor people who answer know where exactly to ask/answer particular subjects.

Anyway, I've deleted the other two copies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like an NFS issue. Is NFS involved?

NFS servers running on Debian-based systems, and possibly others, are configured to ignore supplementary groups unless told specifically otherwise. Ensure that `--manage-gids` has been supplied to the `rpc.mountd` program. On Debian systems that is done by editing `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` and ensuring that `RPCMOUNTDOPTS=--manage-gids` is present.

Comment: Thanks, it was towards the right direction. My server had already `RPCMOUNTDOPTS=--manage-gids` included in the config, but it wasn't a member of my LDAP/Kerberos (IPA) server, so it wasn't able to resolve those GIDs. Thanks.